# Change active "nav-pills" color in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the color when I click on the button of nav-pills, actually i want to delete this action, when i click, something like that:

Img Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuoYX.png
(because i can't post image yet)

In the "stream" button, this happens when i click it, but i want nothing to happen, or at least change to the same as my hover action.

html:

```
<div class='navizinha'>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href='#'>Início</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Inscrição</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Stream</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Tabela</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>F.A.Q</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

and my css:

```
.nav-pills a {
    color: #ffffff
}

.nav-pills a:hover {
    color: #560000;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.nav-pills .active a:hover {
    color: #560000;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you also need to target the `:focus` state via CSS, like this:

```
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #560000;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/Gh801XH2l7)**

**[More about the focus state on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/)**

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

And there's some way to remove it?

Comment: Just change it to what you want. You can't remove the hover state itself, just change its appearance.

Comment: How would you do this for bootstap components using python in dash? Do you change it in styles?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can give this a try

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
background-color:yourBgColor;
color:yourLinkColor;
}
```

From [this link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-change-nav-links-color-when-using-boot-strap)